# StatusBar colour never changes when using NavigationBars on iOS 7

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uinavigationbar, statusbar, uistatusbar

I am trying to change the app StatusBar colour and it works ONLY when my XIB has no navigationBars. To do so, I added the following function to my source file:

```
-(UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle{
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}
```

But when I call `[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:NO];` the status bar goes back to the default style.

It leads me to believe that the navigation bar should set the statusBar colour for itself.

Ant suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed this setting a unique StatusBar colour for the whole app instead of doing it for each ViewController. It took only 2 steps:

1. Defined **“View controller-based status bar appearance” = NO** on MyAppName-Info.plist
2. Added the following line to my **- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions** AppDelegate function

> `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];`

It worked for me =)